# Detecting empty strings in a vector and replacing each empty string by its previous element

Tags: r

Let's say I have this vector:

```
vector <- c("hello", "", "sometimes!","", "goodbye", "okay")
```

and I would like to replace each empty string by its previous item.

At first, I thought about using

```
Library(stringi) #package
stri_isempty(vector)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

to know which element is empty, but now, I am stuck.

I would like to get this result:

```
[1] "hello"      "hello"      "sometimes!" "sometimes"  "goodbye"    "okay"
```

What should I do next?

Thank you

---

Edit: Also, what should I add to the suggested answers if I want to add

```
"final"
```

in front of each empty strings?

Edit 2: I was able to add another string in front of the previous item using the code of Erik Kornet:

```
for (v in 1:length(vector)){
    if (vector[v] == ""){
      vector[v] = paste("final", vector[v-1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can replace `""` with `NA`, and then use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package.

```
vec <- c("hello", "", "sometimes!","", "goodbye", "okay")

library(zoo)
vec[vec %in% ""] <- NA
vec2 <- na.locf(vec)
vec2
# [1] "hello"      "hello"      "sometimes!" "sometimes!" "goodbye"    "okay"
```

Answer (score 3):

A good practice when you want to replace with shifted value is to create a shifted vector to avoid the use of loops and use directly boolean selection:

```
vector <- c("hello", "", "sometimes!","", "goodbye", "okay")
vector_shift <- c(NA,vector[1:length(vector)]) # create a vactor of same length but shifted
vector[vector == ""] <- vector_shift[vector == ""]

[1] "hello"      "hello"      "sometimes!" "sometimes!" "goodbye"    "okay"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with a simple for loop, replacing `vector[x]` with `vector[x-1]` where `vector[x] == ""`:

```
vector <- c("hello", "", "sometimes!","", "goodbye", "okay")

for (v in 1:length(vector)){
    if (vector[v] == ""){
      vector[v] = vector[v-1]
    }
}

> vector
[1] "hello"      "hello"      "sometimes!" "sometimes!" "goodbye"
[6] "okay"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have at most 1 missing at a time, you can try this:

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table) # alternatively you can use library(DataCombine) with shift(vector, -1) below
vector<- ifelse(stri_isempty(vector), shift(vector, 1), vector)
```

Now if you have more, e.g:

```
vector <- c("hello", "", "", "", "sometimes!","", "goodbye", "okay")
vector
#[1] "hello"      ""           ""           ""           "sometimes!" ""           "goodbye"   
#[8] "okay"
```

This `while` loop will do it:

```
while(any(stri_isempty(vector))){
   vector<- ifelse(stri_isempty(vector), shift(vector, 1), vector)
}
vector
#[1] "hello"      "hello"      "hello"      "hello"      "sometimes!" "sometimes!" "goodbye"   
#[8] "okay"
```

Finally, if it was in a dataframe, you can use the `FillDown` function from `DataCombine` (but it's kind of funky, so watch out)

```
library(DataCombine)
df<- data.frame(id = 1:length(vector), vector=as.character(vector))
df$vector<- ifelse(stri_isempty(df$vector), NA, as.character(df$vector))
FillDown(df, "vector")
# id     vector
#1  1      hello
#2  2      hello
#3  3      hello
#4  4      hello
#5  5 sometimes!
#6  6 sometimes!
#7  7    goodbye
#8  8       okay
```

Comment: can you give your packages ? I have `Error in shift(vector, -1) : n must be non-negative integer values (>= 0)` and `Error in stri_isempty(vector) : could not find function "stri_isempty"`

Comment: @denis `stri_isempty` was in the original question, so I guess I just copied it, but you're right about `shift`. In any case, I added the packages.

Comment: Is the `fill` function in `tidyr` less funky than `FillDown`?

Comment: @KerryJackson, I'm not sure how they compare. To be fair, `FillDown` is pretty good, but it needs special attention when it comes to character vectors.